# Adjunctions from triangle isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, 2-categories

A very elementary result in category theory allow us to promote equivalences of categories to adjoint equivalences by changing one of the two natural isomorphisms. Generalizing this, consider the following situation.

> Let $F\colon\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ and
> $G\colon\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}$ be two functors equipped with two natural
> transformations $\eta\colon \text{id}_{\mathcal{A}}\Rightarrow GF$ and
> $\epsilon\colon FG\Rightarrow\text{id}_B$ such that $\epsilon F\cdot F\eta$ and $G\epsilon\cdot\eta G$ are isomorphisms (i.e. we replace each identity of the triangle identities with an isomorphism).

I'd like to show (if it is true) that we can promote $F$ and $G$ to an adjoint pair by suitably replacing $\eta$ and $\epsilon$, ideally with an argument that holds in any $2$-category rather than just in $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: I think if you let $\beta := \epsilon F \circ F\eta$ and $\tilde\epsilon := \epsilon \circ (\beta G)^{-1}$, $(\eta, \tilde\epsilon)$ should satisfy the triangle identities. This is at least true in $\mathbf{Cat}$, but the proof I have in mind doesn't actually go through proving this, so I believe it should hold in an arbitrary $2$-category, but for some reason I have trouble doing the computations involved (they *should* be straightforward but I guess I'm too tired)

Comment: (I'm not yet writing this as an official answer because I haven't worked out the general case, although, again, it must be easy, but tedious)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with the version with equivalences, you can choose to keep either $\eta$ or $\epsilon$. I will keep $\epsilon$.

First, we have the following identity:
$$\begin{align*}
G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet \eta 
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G) F \bullet  G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet \eta \\
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet G \epsilon F \bullet G F G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet \eta G F \bullet \eta \\
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet G \epsilon F \bullet \eta G F \bullet \eta \\
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta) \bullet \eta \\
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet \eta
\end{align*}$$

Let $\tilde{\eta} = G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet \eta = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F \bullet \eta$. Then $\tilde{\eta}$ and $\epsilon$ satisfy the triangle identities:
$$\begin{align*}
\epsilon F \bullet F \tilde{\eta} & = \epsilon F \bullet F G (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet F \eta \\
& = (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta)^{-1} \bullet (\epsilon F \bullet F \eta) \\
& = \mathrm{id}_F \\
G \epsilon \bullet \tilde{\eta} G & = G \epsilon \bullet (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} F G \bullet \eta G \\
& = (G \epsilon \bullet \eta G)^{-1} \bullet (G \epsilon \eta G) \\
& = \mathrm{id}_G
\end{align*}$$

To me, this is a thoroughly unenlightening proof. I think it is better to prove the special case of categories using the hom-set definition of adjunction and then "use Yoneda" to obtain the above proof for general 2-categories. It really comes down to the following observation: given composable maps $a, b, c$ such that $c \circ b$ and $b \circ a$ are invertible, $a, b, c$ are all invertible; in particular, $(c \circ b)^{-1} \circ c = a \circ (b \circ a)^{-1}$.

Comment: Your last paragraph is exactly what I had in mind in my comment - but didn't have the courage (or wasn't able) to go through those equations. And I didn't know enough $2$-category theory to be sure Yoneda was enough to conclude. Anyways, +1 !

Comment: I don't think the result literally follows by the Yoneda lemma, or even by the Yoneda embedding (unless you first prove the claim for functor 2-categories); what I mean is that you use the same idea as in the proof of the Yoneda lemma and chase the identity morphism through the hom-set bijections to get these equations – which you then re-check for validity in general 2-categories.

Comment: Ah, right ! Yes that's what I had in mind too. But I think I was mainly missing your first identity

Comment: That one comes from my very last remark about $(c \circ b)^{-1} \circ c = a \circ (b \circ a)^{-1}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the various induced hom-set bijections.

Comment: Yes, I figured : that's very neat !